# How to avoid memory leak when using pub sub to call function?

Tags: node.js, express, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-tasks

I stuck on performance issue when using pubsub to triggers the function.

```
//this will call on index.ts
export function downloadService() {
  // References an existing subscription
  const subscription = pubsub.subscription("DOWNLOAD-sub");

  // Create an event handler to handle messages
  // let messageCount = 0;
  const messageHandler = async (message : any) => {
    console.log(`Received message ${message.id}:`);
    console.log(`\tData: ${message.data}`);
    console.log(`\tAttributes: ${message.attributes.type}`);

    // "Ack" (acknowledge receipt of) the message
    message.ack();
    await exportExcel(message);//my function
    // messageCount += 1;
  };


  // Listen for new messages until timeout is hit
  subscription.on("message", messageHandler);
} 

async function exportExcel(message : any) {
 //get data from database
 const movies = await Sales.findAll({
    attributes: [
      "SALES_STORE",
      "SALES_CTRNO",
      "SALES_TRANSNO",
      "SALES_STATUS",
    ],
    raw: true,
  });
  ... processing to excel// 800k rows
  ... bucket.upload to gcs

}
```

The function above is working fine if I trigger ONLY one pubsub message.
However, the function will hit memory leak issue or database connection timeout issue if I trigger many pubsub message in short period of time.

The problem I found is, first processing havent finish yet but others request from pubsub will straight to call function again and process at the same time.

I have no idea how to resolve this but I was thinking implement the queue worker or google cloud task will solve the problem?

Comment: Not sure but why await the excel call? That's where its eating up all your memory I'd guess. Just call it and move on (no await) or put them in a queue to be handled on at a time later. add this `// await exportExcel(message);` or if you're using Deno you could use parallel maps to process N at a time.

Comment: @chovy Hi, I have tried removed the "await" but still the same. Actually the memory issue will happen on processing to excel when this function called 3 above at the same time. Alright, let me try looks at it.

Comment: yeah...that's a heavy process. you need to queue them up. If you're using node there are some queue libraries out there. I forget which ones. But you can say something like "process this array until its empty doing X at a time"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @chovy in the comments, there is a need to queue up the `excelExport` function calls since the function's execution is not keeping up with the rate of invocation. One of the modules that can be used to queue function calls is [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). Please note that the `async` module is not officially supported by Google.

As an alternative, you can employ [flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#flow_control) features on the subscriber side. Data pipelines often receive sporadic spikes in published traffic which can overwhelm subscribers in an effort to catch up. The usual response to high published throughput on a subscription would be to dynamically autoscale subscriber resources to consume more messages. However, this can incur unwanted costs — for instance, you may need to use more VM’s — which can lead to additional capacity planning. Flow control features on the subscriber side can help control the unhealthy behavior of these tasks on the pipeline by allowing the subscriber to regulate the rate at which messages are ingested. Please refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/pub-sub-flow-control-batching-9ba9a75bce3b#:%7E:text=to%2Dend%20latency.-,Flow%20Control%20Features,-Some%20features%20that) for more information on flow control features.